# Ionic build events.js 85 Unhandled error event

Tags: android, windows, sdk, npm, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an ionic project but the error pops up. I've already set up all environmental variables. Everything like node, npm, bower, ionic is working, and the SDK updated with API 22

```
E:\io1\apa>ionic build android

running cordova build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" E:\io1\apa\hooks\after_prepa
re\010_add_platform_class.js E:\io1\apa
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: E:\io1\apa\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: E:\io1\apa\platforms\android\cordova
\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: E:\io1\apa\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit
code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Nitish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Comment: You need to share more info about your project. I suggest that you start from a template project and try your compile. This issue may be triggered by many factors (at least , I have encountered) and is hard to investigate with so few info

Comment: I started from installing cordova and ionic, which is working, Also creating a project using ionic start myproject tabs works fine, and ionic platform add android works fine. But when I try to build my project it flashes this error.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this website: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

Follow each and every step. There are different commands/steps for Windows & IOS platform.
Make sure you have installed nodejs along with ionic, cordova, gulp using the command "npm install -g cordova ionic gulp" in your cmd.

Make sure you have installed all the above components, latest Android SDK in the same drive e.g C:\.. to avoid complications.

Set the environment variables like PATH, JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, etc as mentioned in the link above correctly. Use the latest JDK.

Hope this may help.